# Fetching Source IpAddress of the broadmessage meesage recieved on port 137

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, modem, packet-capture

I am trying to fetch the IP address from the broadcast packets sent by a DSL modem and received on port 137 using UDP protocol. I am able to read the IP address when connectivity is present.

However, in unidentified network state, when my modem is configured for DHCP, and a specific range of IPs are allowed, and setting on my machine is auto-detect:

I get the default Local IP Address of the machine on reading the broadcast messages. That would be starting with 169.

Note: I am restarting the modem in order to receive the broadcast messages.

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 137);
                sock.Bind(iep);
                EndPoint ep = (EndPoint)iep;
                int iLoopCount=0;
                while (iLoopCount <= 10000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ready to receive…");
                    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                    int recv = sock.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ep);                    
                    string stringData = Encoding.Default.GetString(data, 0, recv);
                    Console.WriteLine("{1}: from: {0}",((IPEndPoint)ep).Address.ToString(),DateTime.Now.ToString());

                    iLoopCount++;
                   // Console.WriteLine(sock.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                }
                sock.Close();
                Console.Read();
```

Comment: Are you saying that you can't retrieve an IP address when your DHCP server is rebooting or otherwise in a non-operational state? If your host is configured to auto retrieve an IP address, I think you need to rethink your process cause that's the whole point. Aside from that, I'm not really sure what the issue you're having is.

Comment: When the DHCP server reboots, I am able to see the Nbtns packets on the Wireshark and network monitor with source ip address as 192.168.1.252(modem IP Address). I am trying to fetch the Source IpAddress from the same packets using c# UDP listener placed at 137 port. The ip address is being retrieved as 169.254.x.x instead of 192.168.1.252.

Comment: I'm still unsure of what your issue is? Are you saying that after your DHCP server comes back online you can't pull the IP from your local host? If you're pinging an IP from your "DHCP server", you probably resolved an IP address yourself. Edit: I submitted this before your edit, disregard

Comment: is there a reason you need to sniff NetBIOS packets to do this, or is just retrieving the modem/dhcp/server address when it comes online sufficient?

Comment: I got the answer, Able to fetch the IPAddress of the hub with DHCP settings by sniffing the packets and extracting the Source IP of the headers.    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question at
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C